# System Web HttpException (Renderbody) in MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an **online shop in MVC** and now working on its design, i downloaded 2 bootstraps templates , and tried each one, i copied the code in the index in the download file to my `_layout.cshtml` , and after running the project i am getting this **`error`** : 
**System.Web.HttpException: The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".**

can you help me please, this is `my _Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */
        .jumbotron {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
        footer {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>Online Store</h1>
            <p>Mission, Vission & Values</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Your Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>

    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <p>Online Store Copyright</p>
        <form class="form-inline">
            Get deals:
            <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no **@RenderBody()** method in your _Layout page. Add that then run again. Bdw you need to learn MVC from the scratch :)

Comment: but where to add this rendor body? i am a beginner in MVC , that's why i need some help please, thanks! @BasantaMatia

Comment: Check below ans

Comment: yeah but where to add it in my case? @LaxmanGite

Comment: Updated my Ans for second lay out as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place @RenderBody in side the body tag then it will work Here you go :

```
<body>
@RenderBody() 
</body>
```

**And your First Layout Page Should be like this :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */
        .jumbotron {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
        footer {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>Online Store</h1>
            <p>Mission, Vission & Values</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Your Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
                    <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>
 @* here you have to add RenderBody Section *@   
<div>
  @RenderBody()
</div>

    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <p>Online Store Copyright</p>
        <form class="form-inline">
            Get deals:
            <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**And your Second Layout Page Should be like this :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">Shop Name</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">

                <div class="row carousel-holder">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">First Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">Second Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">Third Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">Fourth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">Fifth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <h4><a href="#">Like this template?</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p>If you like this template, then check out <a target="_blank" href="http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-1-building-a-review-system/">this tutorial</a> on how to build a working review system for your online store!</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-1-building-a-review-system/">View Tutorial</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <div class="container">

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
      @* here you have to add RenderBody Section *@   
        <div>
        @RenderBody()
        </div>

    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i am comparing each one , i will choose only one in the end, just checking for best design @LaxmanGite

Comment: Ohh both are best you can use any one of that you have already added bootstrap classes

Comment: i want to choose which design is better , so where to enter the render body in this 2nd layout , thanks! @LaxmanGite

Comment: i just want to know where to add render body in the 2nd layout @LaxmanGite

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Laxman Gite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45073253/7831383), you have to know that **_layout.cshtml** serves as a masterpage, which means its content will usually appear on every page of your app.

It is like a wrapper, so for each page you'll have :

```
[everything up the @RenderBody() in your _layout.cshtml]
[your view's body]
[everything down the @RenderBody() in your _layout.cshtml]
```

This is why you need to include the `@RenderBody()` in your **_layout.cshtml**

Comment: ohhh ok , thanks @Rafalon , this was a useful answer too , thanks!